# How to keep hdpi,mdpi,ldpi and xhdpi files in the Android asset folder?

Tags: android, icons, grouping, drawable, assets

I know it's not possible to create subfolders in android drawable folder and we can use the asset folder to keep our external files. My problem is how do we store the hdpi,mdpi,ldpi and xhdpi resources separately in the asset folder. The app Im developing has around 75 icons and I need to maintain icons for each resolution level and need to categorize the icons according to the some categories in the app.

Your advice is highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards
Pathum

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for switching between assets based on the device configuration. I suggest using a naming convention for your icons to correspond to your categories and using the resources folder. If you post more details, I can suggest specific ways of doing this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Ted, Yeah that is the only way it seems. But the only issue is the maintenance of the project will be difficult. I have around 7-8 separate screens with 12-12 icons in each and some more icons which are common to the app. Maintaining a naming convention is ok but when the number of icons getting bigger its really a hard thing to manage the project.